# how to create a circular image in android... as google+ is using

Tags: android

I am trying to create a circular image, by putting a circular transparent image over it...
But I want to create the circular image as in Google+, is there any other way, without using canvas?

```
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
                                Paint paint = new Paint();
                                    paint.setShader(shader);
                                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                                    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                                    paint.setDither(true);      
                                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
                                Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                                c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint);
                                img.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);    
    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());    
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

or use a mask that have into the center a transparent circle

Comment: Welcome, if this response helps you don't forget to vote

Answer (score 0):

In `android.support.v4` a new class is introduced for creating circular image or rounded cornered image.
Which is `RoundedBitmapDrawable`there's no need to use customized methods.To set any image as round cornered or circular follow the below syntax.

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(pixels);
imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

It's that simple. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)